I am trying to import valid packages, but they are not recognized by flutter
I am using VSCode, and I tried to use the sensors plus package as shown exactly in the documentation:
I tried to find a fix, but couldn't find any, would be glad if someone can help me..
I am trying to use the gyroscope information to detect whether the phone is moving. Unfortunately, doesn't work and I got stuck with a bunch of errors.

run flutter pub get, if it doesn't work restart your vs code

can you show the errors?

HI I faced the same issue but can resolved by flutter clean and then flutter pub get

Importing the code is not enough by itself. You also have to add a dependency to your pubspec.yaml file.
This can be done three ways:

Run flutter pub add sensors_plus on the command line which will install the package and add it to the dependencies in your pubspec.yaml

Use the dart vscode plugin. In VSCode, type ctrl-shift-p (command-shift-p on mac) to run a command then type dart dependency which should select the dart: add dependency command, press enter, then type sensors_plus.

Manually add the following code to your pubspec.yaml then run flutter pub get:


dependencies:
  sensors_plus: ^5.0.1

Note that you will almost certainly have a dependencies section already, so you should simply add the sensors_plus line to that if you go this route.

Thanks a lot! I really appreciate this, couldn't find a helpful resource on the web, showing how to solve this problem

You can done this ways:

In pubspec.yaml file place this package like
dependencies:
sensors_plus: ^5.0.1

Then open terminal and run flutter clean or flutter pub cache clean

After that again run flutter pub get


